# Flutter web: How to allow overflow outside browser window?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

In a Flutter web app, I would like to set a minimum width for my outer container. If the Window gets smaller than that, the content should be able to overflow out of sight (like many websites do).

I was able to achieve it without any visible errors on screen using the OverflowBox with a minWidth constraint, but it still (justifiedly so) shows a lot of errors in the console.

Is there a better / more elegant solution for this (or a way to disable the error messages for this particular widget?)

Comment: in my case i wraped with scaffold, and 3 different layout based on screen size.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Too bad there is no straightforward way to do this.

Comment: do you need it to scroll horizontally?

Comment: @galki Thank you for your response. That would be the ideal scenario, but it's not of crucial importance. The main use-case is that containers are not indefinitely down-sizing themselves if a the browser window is made smaller by the user (e.g. is put on half screen width). Currently this leads to very narrow containers that all try to fit themselves into the available screen width (or an overflow error)

Comment: I get no console errors using OverflowBox with *maxWidth*